# Выбор аргументов в функции

Tags: r

Для определенности возьмем какую-нибудь базовую функцию типа `subset`.
Я столкнулся с такой строкой:  `subset(sel = -rating, sub = rating < 50, attitude)`, (attitude - встроенная небольшая табличка с данными в R), правильно ли я понимаю, что если мы указываем куда мы передаем аргумент, то без разницы на какой он позиции в вызове функции?
Просто обычно в языках у нас есть: `f(x_1, x_2)` и мы должны при вызове `f`, на 1 позицию передать именно то что мы хотим передать в `x_1`, а в `x_2`, то что хотим передать туда.

Comment: Простите, если этот вопрос показался глупым. По умолчанию в документации у `subset` стоит `# S3 method for class 'data.frame'
subset(x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У функции есть список аргументов по умолчанию, например, как Вы привели для функции `subset`.

```
subset(x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...)
```

Т.е. функция ожидает, что Вы передадите ей аргументы в указанном порядке, но если Вы прямо указываете названия аргументов, то порядок можно менять.
Небольшой пример:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
z <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
dt <- data.frame(x, y, z)

subset(dt, z == 1)
#   x y z
# 1 1 5 1
# 2 2 6 1

subset(z == 1, x = dt)
#   x y z
# 1 1 5 1
# 2 2 6 1
```